# What is causing a `setSpan` error on `AutoCompleteTextViews`?

Tags: java, android, autocompletetextview

**Problem:** In the debug report below, I think I understand the issue is the `setSpan` starts at a negative vs 0. But I don't know what that means or whether I can fix it because it isn't traced to any particular layout, class or function I have created? I don't have any code in this activity dealing with `setSpan`?

**What appears to be happening:** It seems to be occurring with `AutoCompleteTextViews` on my  `AddNote` activity. The irony, this activity is really a duplicate of the `EditNote` activity in layout and function, and doesn't occur with `EditNote`. However, one difference is with the `AddNote` activity these have `setOnFocusChangedListener`s.

It also, in one way, appears random. Sometimes I simply click on the `AutoCompleteTextView` and it will trigger this error. Other times, after data is selected or entered, when focus changes it occurs.

**What is expected:** `AutoCompleteTextViews` are dropdown lists with the option to select or to add something new. I've been working with this activity for months with no issue, then this just started to happen.

Below, the debug doesn't identify any of my classes or resources triggering this issue, I just appears to be occurring based upon the few details above. That's one reason I'm not certain if it is something I can change for fix and wanted to reach out.

**AutoCompleteTextView object setups**

```
    ArrayAdapter<String> summaryAdapter = DBQueryTools.captureSummaries(this);
    summary.setThreshold(1);
    summary.setAdapter(summaryAdapter);

    ArrayAdapter<String> topicsAdapter = DBQueryTools.captureDBTopics(this);
    topic.setThreshold(1);
    topic.setAdapter(topicsAdapter);

    ArrayAdapter<String> acQuestionAdapt = DBQueryTools.captureDBQuestions(this);
    question.setThreshold(1);
    question.setAdapter(acQuestionAdapt);
```

**Adapter Code**

```
public static ArrayAdapter<String> captureDBTopics(Context context){
    rdb = ResearchDatabase.getInstance(context, "Apologetic.db");
    List<Topics> topics = rdb.getTopicsDao().getTopics();
    List<String> orgTopics = new ArrayList<>();
    for(Topics t : topics){
        orgTopics.add(t.getTopic());
    }
    return new ArrayAdapter<>(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, orgTopics);
    //topic.setAdapter(topicsAdapter);
}
public static ArrayAdapter<String> captureDBQuestions(Context context){
    rdb = ResearchDatabase.getInstance(context, "Apologetic.db");
    List<Questions> questions = rdb.getQuestionsDao().getQuestions();
    List<String> orgQuestions = new ArrayList<>();
    for(Questions q : questions){
        orgQuestions.add(q.getQuestion());
    }
    return new ArrayAdapter<>(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, orgQuestions);
    //question.setAdapter(acQuestionAdapt);
}
public static ArrayAdapter<String> captureSummaries(Context context){
    rdb = ResearchDatabase.getInstance(context, "Apologetic.db");
    List<Comments> summaries = rdb.getCommentsDao().getComments();
    List<String> orgSummaries = new ArrayList<>();
    for(Comments c : summaries){
        if(!c.getSummary().isEmpty() && !orgSummaries.contains(c.getSummary().trim()))
            orgSummaries.add(c.getSummary());
    }
    return new ArrayAdapter<>(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, orgSummaries);
}
```

**Debug**

```
E/InputEventReceiver: Exception dispatching input event.
E/MessageQueue-JNI: Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
E/MessageQueue-JNI: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: setSpan (-1 ... -1) starts before 0
        at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.checkRange(SpannableStringBuilder.java:1326)
        at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.setSpan(SpannableStringBuilder.java:682)
        at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.setSpan(SpannableStringBuilder.java:674)
        at android.text.Selection.setSelection(Selection.java:93)
        at android.text.Selection.setSelection(Selection.java:77)
        at android.text.method.ArrowKeyMovementMethod.onTouchEvent(ArrowKeyMovementMethod.java:291)
        at android.widget.TextView.onTouchEvent(TextView.java:10089)
        at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:12513)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3030)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2719)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3030)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2719)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3030)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2719)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3030)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2719)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3030)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2719)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3030)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2719)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3030)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2719)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3030)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2719)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:440)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1830)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:3400)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:69)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:69)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:398)
        at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:12752)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5106)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4909)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4426)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4479)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4445)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4585)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4453)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4642)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4426)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4479)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4445)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4453)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4426)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7092)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:7061)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7022)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7195)
        at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:186)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:326)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:160)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.mistywillow.researchdb, PID: 27233
    java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: setSpan (-1 ... -1) starts before 0
        at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.checkRange(SpannableStringBuilder.java:1326)
        at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.setSpan(SpannableStringBuilder.java:682)
        at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.setSpan(SpannableStringBuilder.java:674)
        at android.text.Selection.setSelection(Selection.java:93)
        at android.text.Selection.setSelection(Selection.java:77)
        at android.text.method.ArrowKeyMovementMethod.onTouchEvent(ArrowKeyMovementMethod.java:291)
        at android.widget.TextView.onTouchEvent(TextView.java:10089)
        at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:12513)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3030)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2719)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3030)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2719)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3030)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2719)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3030)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2719)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3030)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2719)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3030)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2719)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3030)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2719)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3030)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2719)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:440)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1830)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:3400)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:69)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:69)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:398)
        at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:12752)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5106)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4909)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4426)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4479)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4445)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4585)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4453)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4642)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4426)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4479)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4445)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4453)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4426)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7092)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:7061)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7022)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7195)
        at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:186)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:326)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:160)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be a common and frequent issue posted on Issue Tracker. I added comments to the following issue which appeared to be similar and had been assigned.
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/119349156